# Setting default value for Date field in Grails Domain Class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to set a default value for a `Date` field in a Domain class.

I can use `defaultValue` in the `mapping` configuration but it doesn't work with `Date` fields (I've tried it on `String` and `Integer` and it works fine).

This is an example:

```
class Something {

    Date myField

    static mapping = {
        myField defaultValue: new Date()
    }

}
```

This code fails because the CREATE statement that Hibernate generates is incorrect. It is something like:

```
... my_field datetime default Mon Nov 25 17:59:08 UYST 2013 not null ...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always initialize the field in the static initializer or set the value in the constructor:

```
class Something {
    // initializer
    Date myField = new Date()

    // or in the ctor
    Something() {
        myField = new Date()
    }
}
```

This doesn't set a default value in the database schema, it merely sets the value of the field on creation of the instance. If you want the schema to have a default value, you can use the 'defaultValue' mapping entry like so:

```
class Something {
    Date myField

    static mapping = {
        myField defaultValue: "now()"
    }
}
```

the value you set for the default value is dependent on your database vendor. (notice the use of sql `now()` method rather than Java/Groovy `new Date()`.

Comment: Thanks! I supposed that was the solution, but didn't want a database engine specific function like now()

Answer (score 2):

GORM readily caters for the most basic `Date` use cases; create and update.

Simply include keywords `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` into the domain's properties for the *default* functionality to occur.

Warning: If their constraints are `nullable: false` this will cause a fail. Either remove those constraints or set `autoTimestamp` to false.

For example:

```
class MyDomain {
   Date dateCreated
   Date lastUpdated
   Date yesterday = new Date().previous()
   Date weekAgo = new Date() - 7
   Date monthAgo = new Date() - 30
   Date usaIndepenceDay = new Date().copyWith(
         year: 1776, 
         month: Calendar.JULY, 
         dayOfMonth: 4, 
         hourOfDay: 0,
         minute: 0,
         second: 0)

   static mapping = {
     //autoTimestamp false
   }

   static constraints = {
     //dateCreated nullable: false
   }
}
```

Read the more about groovy dates at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848000/how-to-create-new-date-in-groovy-at-specific-date-and-time) SO answer, the [groovy date api](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DateGroovyMethods.html#previous(java.util.Date)), and GORM's date-event features [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/GORM.html#advancedGORMFeatures)

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about the dateCreated and lastUpdated fields, but those had nothing to do with my original question :D

Comment: I loosely threw them in there because I couldn't find a good and fast answer on grails dates, and adds something easy to digest

Comment: How would I set the default date to tomorrows date? Or say four days from now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for default crated date auto get from system date

```
class User {
String userName
String firstName
String lastName
Date createdDate = new Date() // set system date


static mapping = {
    version false
    id generator: 'increment'
    cache true
}

static constraints = {
    userName(unique: true)
}
}
```