# Set a Grails domain attribute's defaultValue to Joda-Time Period.ZERO

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-orm, jodatime

I have been using the Joda-Time plugin for Grails. I'm really starting to love it but, I'm trying to set a default value for domain attribute (Period type:PersistentPeriod). Everything is working great. I can save and retrieve Joda-Time data, the tag library is working well, calculations and conversions are flawless but, everything blows up when I try to compile after setting a default value for a Joda-Time attributes.
Example:

```
class Person { 
    DateTime date 
    Period totalTime 
    static mapping = {
        totalTime (type: PersistentPeriod, defaultValue:Period.ZERO)
        date (type: PersistentDateTime, defaultValue:DateTime.now())
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to do this with default values or should I keep the Joda-Time attributes nullable and blank.

Comment: What actually blows up ? Please provide a stack trace or error description.

Comment: SchemaExport Unsuccessful:
SchemaExport Column "PT0S" not found; SQL statement:
SchemaExport Table "ACCT_SHIFT" not found; SQL statement:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying "defaultValue" won't work in the way you are trying to use it. It is meant to be used as a default value that MySQL can use when specifying the create table syntax. If you simply want any class that doesn't have the value set to be a default then rewrite your Person class like so:

```
class Person { 
  DateTime date = DateTime.now() 
  Period totalTime = Period.ZERO
  static mapping = {
    totalTime (type: PersistentPeriod)
    date (type: PersistentDateTime)
  } 
}
```

Alternatively you could use defaultValue: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" for DateTime.now() by MySQL will expect a field type "TIMESTAMP" and not "DATETIME" in order for it to work.

Comment: That works. I guess I misunderstood the use of defaultValue. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: After researching a little more about defaultValue, and considering @th3morg comments, I realized that 'defaultValue' in the mapping closure specifically affects the creation and update of the database. Therefore, the value assigned to defaultValue must correspond to a 'native' data type of the database I am using. 
So this works: totalTime (type: PersistentPeriod, defaultValue:"PT0S") -- "PT0S" being the actual string Joda-Time stores in the database column, a varchar(255).

Comment: The declaration of a default value in the property, 'Period totalTime = Period.ZERO' is used by GORM when the application saves/updates a domain object and there is no value/null value for the totalTime attribute. [See this Nabble post about defaultValue.](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/right-way-to-define-default-value-to-a-properties-in-domain-class-td4649809.html)
I think I'm understanding this correctly. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ... and yet another amendment to this topic. "PT0S" does not work. Not as specifically typed. "'PT0S'" works.

Comment: ... and another. the date in the mapping closure can be set like this:
date type: PersistentDateTime, defaultValue: "now()". This also works for the standard Grails Date data type. [See this other StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202702/setting-default-value-for-date-field-in-grails-domain-class)