# How to create new Date in Groovy at specific date and time

Tags: date, groovy

I wonder if there is other way how to create new `Date` in Groovy at specific date and time than parse it from `String` with `Date.parse` method. Can I get complete list of `Date` creation in Groovy?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the existing Java methods to create a date:

```
// takes the date encoded as milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC
def mydate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

// create from an existing Calendar object
def mydate = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.APRIL, 3, 1, 23, 45).time
```

Groovy also provides some streamlined extensions for creating Dates.  [`Date.parse()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`Date.parseToStringDate()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parseToStringDate(java.lang.String)) parse it from a String. The [`Date.copyWith()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#copyWith(java.util.Map)) method builds a date from a map.  You can use them like this:

```
// uses the format strings from Java's SimpleDateFormat
def mydate = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", "2014-04-03 1:23:45")

// uses a format equivalent to EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
def mydate = Date.parseToStringDate("Thu Apr 03 01:23:45 UTC 2014")

def mydate = new Date().copyWith(
    year: 2014, 
    month: Calendar.APRIL, 
    dayOfMonth: 3, 
    hourOfDay: 1,
    minute: 23,
    second: 45)
```

Comment: Wow nice one and the most readable one I've seen so far. If you could complete other possible ways of creating `Date` I will definitely accept your answer.

Comment: Here is the other way. [`set()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#set(java.util.Map)). `def mydate = new Date();
mydate.set(year: 2014, month: Calendar.APRIL, dayOfMonth: 3, hourOfDay: 1, minute: 23, second: 45)` @michal.kreuzman

Comment: Good point @dmahapatro.  That one has the advantage of not creating an extra Date object.  Too bad it doesn't return the Date object so it can't be used as an initializer.

Comment: Agree. That is why did not add as an update to your answer. ;) `copyWith()` was a better fit compared to `set()`.

Comment: Deprecated, check Basil Bourque answer

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are outdated as of Java 8 and later. The old legacy date-time classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar/.GregorianCalendar have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework supplants those old classes.

Groovy can use these classes of course. I do not know the Groovy syntax, but it should be easy to adapt this simple Java example.

### `LocalDate`/`LocalTime`

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and `LocalTime` classes have no concept of time zone. So they do not represent actual moments on the timeline.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate( 2016 , Month.JANUARY , 2 ); // year, month, date.
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime( 12 , 30 , 0 , 0 ); // hour, minute, second, nanosecond.
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3-4 zone abbreviations commonly seen.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( localDate , localTime , zoneId );
```

### `Instant`

You should avoid the old date-time classes. But if required, you can convert. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is the java.time class to represent a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. Look for new methods on the old java.util.Date class for converting to/from an `Instant`. We can extract the needed `Instant` object from our `ZonedDateTime`.

### Nanosecond vs Millisecond

Note that **converting *from* java.time involves data loss**! The java.time classes support [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution (up to 9 digits of decimal place on fractional second) while the old java.util.Date supports only [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) (up to 3 decimal places). Any 4th to 9th digit of fractional second is truncated. For example, `2016-04-28T02:05:05.123456789` is truncated to `2016-04-28T02:05:05.123`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

Going the other direction, from java.util.Date to `Instant`. The 4th to 9th decimal place of fractional second will be zeros, the 1st-3rd for any milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = utilDate.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 7):

Groovy is good.

```
new Date(2016-1900, 7, 16, 20, 32, 25)
```

Tue Aug 16 20:32:25 PDT 2016

Note that the year must be massaged, but you can create a new Java Date representing any second you want.

You can see more Groovy Goodness at http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-dates.html

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no other way. You can also pass exact time in millis to constructor of Date class but first You need to get the time in millis.

Maybe this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-create-new) will be helpful.

Or this code snippet:

```
def calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2011,1,7,15,7,23)
def date = calendar.getTime()
println date
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get current date using `Date()` and format it the way you want using:

```
    /*
     y: year
     m: month
     d: day
     h: hour
     m: minute
    */

Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm') 
Date().format('yy/mm/dd hh')
```

The return type is a string.

Answer (score 0):

LocalDateTime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).